# Sphinx- How to autodoc .py files located within multiple folders?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am new to both Python and Sphinx and am attempting to autodoc python files located in a directory structured similar to the following:

```
Project
├── Sphinx
|   ├── index.rst
|   ├── autodoc.rst
|   └──  conf.py
├── Scripts
|   ├── file1.py
|   └──  file2.py
|   ├── folder
|   |   └── file3.py
```

My conf.py file contains:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../Scripts/"))
```

And autodoc contains:

```
.. automodule:: file1
  :members:

.. automodule:: file2
  :members:

.. automodule:: folder.file3
  :members:
```

File3.py is not autodoc'ing correctly (Error: No module named metric.billpay)

I've also tried:

```
.. automodule:: folder/file3
  :members:
```

But I receive

> WARNING: invalid signature for automodule (u'folder/file3')
>
> WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting
>   u'folder/file3' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive
>   in the document, or giving an explicit module name)

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am new to Python, Sphinx, and StackOverflow, so my apologies if there are problems with this question.

Comment: Question related to your setup -- how were you able to automatically generate the automodule lines for file1, file2, etc.?

Answer (score 8):

In addition too:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("..Scripts/"))
```

I added this afterward:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("..Scripts/Folder/"))
```

Which allowed me to access files in Folder with autodoc.

Comment: Wow. I've been bashing my head against a wall with the same sort of problem for the last 2 days, trying *everything* except this. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect there was no `__init__.py` in the `Scripts` folder.

Adding to the `sys.path` is something you should only need at the root, it at all (better to be in an environment where the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is correctly set to have the packages found.

The only exception I sometimes find to this is if I need to add a tests folder in addition to my main source folder.